# Is there a way for the jQuery plugin select2 to retain the class of each select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using the jQuery plugin [select2](https://select2.github.io/) and I'm wondering if there was any way that you could make it retain (merge) a class you have set on each `option` element in the inital `select` field and insert it as an additional class in the resulting `li` tag?

So currently they get a class of `select2-results__option`; what I want would be something like: `select2-results__option myclass`.

Can this be done?

Also, it doesn't *have* to be a class, even retaining a `data` attribute would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentaiton for the select2 plugin, you can do this by overriding the function that creates the results https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

```
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="vendor/images/flags/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};



$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

Comment: That example you have shown allows me to edit the data _inside_ the `<li>` tag, is there anyway to put/edit the `<li>` tag itself?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because it's the cleanest solution and is currently how I have other code setup; at the moment I have a pseudo element on the `<li>` based off of what child they are, however I now need to change that to be based off of the class, hence I want to add the class to the same `<li>` tag, however if this can't be done then I guess I will go the alternate route. :)

Comment: Well happy to accept this as it works well enough, just changed my coding around to using a pseudo element on the `span`.